# Como modificar/evoluir um cache distribuído Infinispan "a quente" sem perder entradas?

Tags: java, jboss, replicação

### Contexto

Eu tenho um *cluster* com alguns nós do JBoss EAP 6.4. Aplicações em nós desse *cluster* compartilham um *cache* do Infinispan em modo embarcado com distribuição síncrona via UDP (JGroups):

```xml
<cache-container name="meu-container"
        default-cache="meu-cache"
        jndi-name="java:jboss/infinispan/cache/meu-container">
   <transport stack="udp"/>
   <distributed-cache name="meu-cache" 
         owners="2"  
         mode="SYNC" />
   <!-- Outros caches -->       
</cache-container>
```

Esse cache usa uma `String` como chave e um POJO como valor:

```
@Resource(lookup="java:jboss/infinispan/cache/meu-container/meu-cache")
private Cache<String, MeuPojo> meuCache;
```

`MeuPojo` é um objeto simples `Serializable`:

```
public class MeuPojo implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4L;  
    
    private String campoUm;
    private Integer campoDois;

    // Outros campos, getters, setters, etc

}
```

O *cache* distribuído funciona perfeitamente e todas as instâncias de `meuCache` "enxergam" todas as entradas. Alterações em qualquer instância de `MeuPojo` são vistas em todos nós, novas entradas ou exclusões de entradas em qualquer nó são "refletidas" nos demais nós.

Durante um *upgrade* da aplicação sem atualizações em `MeuPojo` os nós do *cluster* sobem e descem um a um sem prejuízo para o *cache*. Assim que um nó sobe ele ganha acesso à cópia dele das entradas do *cache*.

### O problema

O problema acontece quando modifico `MeuPojo`. Nesse caso o Infinispan não se comporta muito bem devido a diferenças na serialização. Se eu adicionar um novo campo (e.g., `private String campoTres;`) os nós atualizados não conseguem enxergar as entradas com versões não atualizadas do `MeuPojo` no `meuCache` e vice-versa (nós não atualizados não enxergam versões do `MeuPojo` atualizados).

Nada de significativo acontece nos logs independente do valor de `serialVersionUID`. O que me leva a crer que o Infinispan está engolindo exceções como `InvalidClassException`.

Atualmente toda vez que queremos adicionar um novo campo em `MeuPojo` é uma luta. O *workaround* é usar dois caches (`meu-cache` e `meu-cache-v2`) e duas classes diferentes `MeuPojo` e `MeuPojoV2`. Copiamos as entradas manualmente na aplicação e trocamos qual *cache* está "valendo" para as aplicações em cada *upgrade*.

Penso que deve existir uma maneira menos "burra" de evoluir `MeuPojo` sem perder as entradas no cache, porém não consegui encontrar uma solução. O ideal seria que nós atualizados enxergassem entradas em versões não atualizadas de `MeuPojo` (como se eles tivessem `campo3 = null`) e vice-versa.

Alguém já passou por isso e conhece uma solução ou ao menos um *work-around* menos trabalhoso?

Answer (score 2):

Vejo pelo menos duas alternativas possíveis, mas deve existir mais. A primeira delas é a mais simples, porém também mais frágil, e consiste em congelar o conjunto de campos da classes existente (assim como congelar o `serialVersionUID`) e forçar que novos campos sejam adicionados com o modificador `transient`. Qualquer violação dessa regra vai ocasionar o problema que você descreve.

A outra alternativa é tomar o controle da serialização você mesmo ao implementar os seguintes métodos:

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException;
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
private void readObjectNoData() throws ObjectStreamException;
```

Estes métodos são descritos na documentação da interface [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). Basicamente, eles substituem a forma de serialização padrão e permitem que você defina a sua própria forma particular de realizar a serialização. O método `writeObject` é o responsável por serializar o objeto e o `readObject` por desserializar. O método `readObjectNoData` decide o que fazer quando o objeto a ser criado advém de um *stream* corrompido ou incompatível.

O `ObjectOutputStream` é o objeto responsável por serializar o objeto e ele conhece o objeto que está sendo serializado. Dessa forma, se você usar os métodos [`ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#defaultWriteObject--) e [`ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#defaultReadObject--), os campos não-`transient` do objeto em questão serão serializados e desserializados respectivamente da forma padrão que o java faz. Assim sendo, você pode usar esses métodos para escrever e ler os campos padrão e usar os demais métodos no mesmo *stream* para escrever e ler os valores dos demais campos que estarão marcados como `transient`. Ou então você não usa estes métodos e adiciona/obtém os valores dos campos do objeto manualmente ao usar os demais métodos do *stream*.

Além disso, você também pode preferir implementar a interface [`Externalizable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) para ter um controle melhor sobre o *stream*.

Comment: Fala Victor, belezinha? Infelizmente implementar `Exernalizable` não fez diferença, parece que essa versão do Inifinispan não usa o mecanismo padrão de serialização. Achei na documentação referências a [*JBoss Marshalling*](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Marshalling)  e [*User Defined Externalizers*](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Plugging+Infinispan+With+User+Defined+Externalizers), estou tentando ver se consigo colocar um desses exemplos para funcionar. De qualquer forma obrigado pela ajuda, você apontou na direção correta.